# keep_prob value in dropout and getting worst results with dropout

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, regularized

According to this link, the value of keep_prob has to be between (0,1]:
[Tensorflow manual](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dropout)

Otherwise I'll get value error:

```
ValueError: If keep_prob is not in (0, 1] or if x is not a floating point tensor.
```

I'm using the following code for a simple neural network with one hidden layer:

```
n_nodes_input = len(train_x.columns) # number of input features
n_nodes_hl = 30     # number of units in hidden layer
n_classes = len(np.unique(Y_train_numeric)) 
lr = 0.25
x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, len(train_x.columns)])
y = tf.placeholder('float')
dropout_keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

def neural_network_model(data, dropout_keep_prob):
    # define weights and biases for all each layer
    hidden_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_nodes_input, n_nodes_hl], stddev=0.3)),
                      'biases':tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[n_nodes_hl]))}
    output_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_nodes_hl, n_classes], stddev=0.3)),
                    'biases':tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[n_classes]))}
    # feed forward and activations
    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_layer['weights']), hidden_layer['biases'])
    l1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(l1)
    l1 = tf.nn.dropout(l1, dropout_keep_prob)
    output = tf.matmul(l1, output_layer['weights']) + output_layer['biases']

    return output

def main():
    prediction = neural_network_model(x, dropout_keep_prob)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y,logits=prediction))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr).minimize(cost)

    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    for epoch in range(1000):
        loss = 0
        _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict = {x: train_x, y: train_y, dropout_keep_prob: 4.})
        loss += c

        if (epoch % 100 == 0 and epoch != 0):
            print('Epoch', epoch, 'completed out of', 1000, 'Training loss:', loss)
    correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction,1), tf.argmax(y,1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, tf.float32), name='op_accuracy')

    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('graph',sess.graph)
    writer.close()

    print('Train set Accuracy:', sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict = {x: train_x, y: train_y, dropout_keep_prob: 1.}))
    print('Test set Accuracy:', sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict = {x: test_x, y: test_y, dropout_keep_prob: 1.}))
    sess.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

If I use a number in range (0,1] for dropout_keep_prob in the sess.run, the accuracy drops drastically. If I use a number bigger than 1, like 4, the accuracy goes beyond 0.9. 
Once I use shift+tab in front of tf.nn.dropout(), this is written as part of description:

```
With probability `keep_prob`, outputs the input element scaled up by
`1 / keep_prob`, otherwise outputs `0`.  The scaling is so that the expected
sum is unchanged.
```

which seems to me that keep_prob has to be greater than 1 otherwise nothing would be dropped!

Bottom line, I'm confused. Which part of dropout have I implemented wrong that my results are getting worst and what is a good number for keep_drop?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> which seems to me that keep_prob has to be greater than 1 otherwise nothing would be dropped!

The description says:

> With probability `keep_prob`, outputs the input element scaled up by
>   `1 / keep_prob`, otherwise outputs `0`.  The scaling is so that the expected
>   sum is unchanged.

This means that:

- `keep_prob` is used as a probability, so by definition it should always be in `[0, 1]` (a number outside that range can never be a probability)
- With probability `keep_prob`, input elements are multiplied by `1 / keep_prob`. Since we've just written that `0 <= keep_prob <= 1`, the division `1 / keep_prob` is always going to be greater than `1.0` (or exactly `1.0` if `keep_prob == 1`). So, with probability `keep_prob`, some elements are going to become bigger than they were without dropout
- With probability `1 - keep_prob` (the "otherwise" in the description), elements are set to `0`. This is the dropout, elements are dropped if they got set to `0`. If you set `keep_prob` to exactly `1.0`, this means the probability of dropping any node becomes `0`. So, if you want to drop some nodes, you should set `keep_prob < 1`, and if you don't want to drop anything, you set `keep_prob = 1`.

**Important note:** You only want to use dropout during training, not during testing.

> If I use a number in range (0,1] for dropout_keep_prob in the sess.run, the accuracy drops drastically.

If you do this for the test set, or if you mean you're reporting accuracy on the training set, that doesn't surprise me. Dropout means losing information, so it is indeed going to lose accuracy. It's supposed to be a way of regularizing though; you intentionally lose accuracy during the training phase, but hope this results in improved generalization and therefore improved accuracy during the test phase (when you should no longer be using dropout).

> If I use a number bigger than 1, like 4, the accuracy goes beyond 0.9.

I'm surprised you get this code to run at all. Based on the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.5/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py#L2173), I wouldn't expect it to run?

Comment: Thank you. I wouldn't expect it to run either but it does so I was thinking maybe something is wrong! Upon using dropoout, even 0.9, the accuracy of the unseen test dataset, drops from 0.8-0.9 to about 0.5 and I don't know how to improve it. I'm using the human activities recognition with smartphones dataset with 7352 data for training...

Comment: @user3709260 When you say "using dropout", did you make sure to follow my **important note**? Only use dropout_keep_prob=0.9 (for example) when feeding in train_x and train_y, **always** use dropout_keep_prob=1.0 when feeding in test_x and test_y! If you're already doing that, it's still possible that dropout simply isn't beneficial for your data. It's a regularization technique, used to prevent overfitting. If your training and test distributions are highly similar, and training data size is large enough, it's possible you simply don't need dropout.

Comment: Thanks. Yes indeed I followed all of it.I think you might be right because I've playing around with this for the past two days and it may be the case that there is no point in using dropout for this dataset. Is there a rule or rule of thumb to decide when dropout may not be necessary? Like a parameter or a certain difference to watch for?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. If your training and test data are very very similar, and u have a large amount of training data, it's probably less likely to be useful/necessary